# I am trying to use a for-loop to insert an element of one list to the first element of each list within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

So I am writing a program to automate a budget. I am trying to account for expenses in the newest data that has not previously been part of the budget. The idea is to create a list that stores the value of the expense for each month. I start with a list of 0's as because we've never seen the expense before it was 0 for previous months and now I want to use a for-loop to insert the value for this month but it doesn't seem to work any help would be appreciated.

```
new_expenses = ["petrol", "phone"]
new_expense_values = [""120", "20"]
final_expense_data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]

for i in new_expense_values:
    for j in range(len(new_expenses)):
        final_expense_data[j][0] = i 

print(final_expense_data)
```

Comment: Fix up your `new_expense_values = [""120", "20"]` you have an extra `"` in there Also what's the expected output?

Comment: can you gave an example of desired output

Comment: sorry the extra " is just from me typing it's not the issue, there should be no quotation marks at all. The desired output is as follows: [[120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you firstly write `120` to both lists in `final_expense_data` and then write `20` to both of them (because of `for i in new_expense_values:` loop). You should use the same index for all lists of lists iterating:

```
new_expenses = ["petrol", "phone"]
new_expense_values = ["120", "20"]
final_expense_data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]

for j in range(len(new_expenses)):
    final_expense_data[j][0] = new_expense_values[j] 

print(final_expense_data)
```

> `[['120', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['20', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

---

But I recommend you to use dicts instead of different lists. It is **far** easier to modify your data with them:

```
from pprint import pprint

final_expense_data = {
    'petrol': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'phone': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'waka': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
new_expenses = {
    'petrol': 120,
    'phone': 20,
    'big_red_hat': 11111
}

for e in new_expenses:
    if e in final_expense_data:
        final_expense_data[e][0] = new_expenses[e]
    else:
        final_expense_data[e] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        final_expense_data[e][0] = new_expenses[e]
pprint(final_expense_data)
```

> ```
> {'big_red_hat': [11111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>  'petrol': [120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>  'phone': [20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>  'waka': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sence to use double for loop, with this line:

```
for i in new_expense_values:
```

in first pass you will have:

```
[['120', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['120', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

with second pass you are overwriting to:

```
[['20', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['20', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

code:

```
new_expenses = ["petrol", "phone"]
new_expense_values = ["120", "20"]
final_expense_data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]

for j in range(len(new_expenses)):
    final_expense_data[j][0] = new_expense_values[j]

print(final_expense_data)
```

output:

```
[['120', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['20', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: when I run that code I get the following, [[120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: This has been the problem from the start

Comment: yes its word for word the same and I keep getting the same element repeated in each sub list, thank you for your help though